# react native flatlist value doesn't get updated /re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist where it gets the itemCount from another page, I increment it with a button, its value changes but won't be seen on the screen without pressing ctrl-s or going to another page and return.

```
<FlatList 
extraData={store}
data={store}
renderItem={({ item }) => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.itemCountView}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.up}
          onPress={() => item.itemCount++}>
          <MaterialIcons name="arrow-drop-up" size={36} color="#ddd"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.itemCountText}>{item.itemCount}</Text>
      </View>
  )
}}/>
```

am I missing something? Maybe using the `extraData` the wrong way?

**any type of help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1):

to re-render the flat list you have to pass the variable in extraData which is changing its value.

**extraData prop** - It re renders the flat list when the given variable changes its value.

You can also manage with state variable like eg below : -

```
    const [refreshList, setRefreshList] = useState(false);

    setRefreshList(true);                // set this true where you need

    <FlatList
      data={item.punch_list_inspection}
      style={style.content}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      extraData={refreshList}                  //pass variable here.
      ItemSeparatorComponent={FlatListItemSeparator}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `keyExtractor` to your Flatlist

`keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}`

and it should look like this

```
   <FlatList 
    extraData={store}
    data={store}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => {
      return (
          <View style={styles.itemCountView}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.up}
              onPress={() => item.itemCount++}>
              <MaterialIcons name="arrow-drop-up" size={36} color="#ddd"/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.itemCountText}>{item.itemCount}</Text>
          </View>
      )
    }}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can map it like below

```
{data.map({ item, i }) => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.itemCountView} key={i}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.up}
          onPress={() => item.itemCount++}>
          <MaterialIcons name="arrow-drop-up" size={36} color="#ddd"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.itemCountText}>{item.itemCount}</Text>
      </View>
  )
}}
```